# remove text and add new text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a quote machine for freecodecamp and I'm having a problem. When I click on a button, I am able to get a quote to come onto the screen like so:

> Love all, trust a few, do wrong to none.
>    - William Shakespeare

However, if I click on the button again, instead of the first quote disappearing and the second quote appearing in its place like I want, the second quote adds on after the first quote, like so:

> Love all, trust a few, do wrong to none. Joy is the best makeup. 
>   - William Shakespeare - Anne Lamott

I have tried several different ways to have the first quote removed and the second quote appear in its place. Here is the current version of my code.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
 $.getJSON("https://crossorigin.me/http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en", function(responseText) {
   $(".msg").removeClass();
   $(".nme").removeClass();
  $("#quote").addClass(".msg").append( responseText.quoteText);
   $("#author").addClass(".nme").append(" - " + responseText.quoteAuthor);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button type="button">Get Quote</button>
  <div id="quote"><span class="msg"></span></div>
  <div id="author"><span class="nme"></span></div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like the snippet won't run b/c I don

Comment: You're appending (ie. adding new text to the element) versus just replacing it with .val() or with .text()

Comment: It does run, the problem is that you keep APPENDing the content without emptying it first, that is all you need, clear the msg span before adding a new one.

Comment: Looks like the snippet won't run b/c I did it on Codepen and therefore don't have everything necessary in the code. Here instead is a link to my Codepen: https://codepen.io/dtarvin/pen/pePowj

Comment: David why are you assigning the class msg to quote? Is it because the style is not applied on the span? If that is the case then move the class to the div id="quote" and remove the span entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use Append. Just use text() to completely replace the text. Append takes the current text and appends your new text to it.

ie:

```
.addClass(".msg").text( responseText.quoteText);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `append()` just adds the text a the end:

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

What you really need is replace the content, try with `text()`

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
 $.getJSON("https://crossorigin.me/http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en", function(responseText) {
   $(".msg").removeClass();
   $(".nme").removeClass();
  $("#quote").addClass(".msg").text( responseText.quoteText);
   $("#author").addClass(".nme").text(" - " + responseText.quoteAuthor);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button type="button">Get Quote</button>
  <div id="quote"><span class="msg"></span></div>
  <div id="author"><span class="nme"></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep `.append` ing content to the div, you need to replace it with `.text` like below:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
 $.getJSON("https://crossorigin.me/http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en", function(responseText) {
   $(".msg").removeClass();
   $(".nme").removeClass();
  $("#quote").text( responseText.quoteText);
   $("#author").addClass(".nme").append(" - " + responseText.quoteAuthor);
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <button type="button">Get Quote</button>
  <div id="quote"><span class="msg"></span></div>
  <div id="author"><span class="nme"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Programmer, I don't know what I did to give a down vote. I'm pretty new to stackoverflow and don't know how to use many functions. Sorry about that. Is there a way to undo it?

Comment: Hey David, no worries, you can remove the down vote by going to the left of the message where the -1 is, and hit the up arrow.